# could i use a MCP3008 to output?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi3

I would like to use the **mcp3008** to drive motors, or switch on led arrays for example, until now i only found how to read analog sensor using raspberry pi gpio.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. MCP3008 is an analog-to-digital converter. It is an input device.